# Is the arrival segment of an IAP in PANS-OPS the equivalent of FAA's feeder route?

Tags: iaps, terps, pans-ops

In *ICAO*'s manual 8168 ("Aircraft Operations"), the term "Feeder route" is never mentioned. Instead, it states:

> **8168 Volume II, "Approach Procedures":** 1.2.3. Segments of the approach procedure. An instrument approach procedure may have five separate segments. They are the **arrival**, initial,intermediate, final and missed approach segments.

My confusion concerns the difference between the arrival segment and a *STAR*. Does the arrival segment imply that it is also part of an arrival procedure, or is it just the equivalent of a feeder route, which is mentioned in *FAA*'s TERPS?

Could someone help me clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrival segment can be part of both an arrival route and a designated STAR. Both are protected with the same design criteria.

The STAR chart consist of designated routes linking the approach procedure with ATS-routes or exit points in Free Route Airspace (FRA). An arrival route is simply a collection of arrival segments which are not part of a STAR when it is not operationally necessary to publish the route using the STAR criteria in ICAO DOC 8168 Vol. II Part I, Section 4, Chapter 2. The non-STAR arrival routes are published on the Instrument Approach Chart (IAC) as part of the Instrument Approach Procedure (IAP).

[Here is an example](https://ais.avinor.no/no/AIP/View/59/aip/ad/ensk/EN_AD_2_ENSK_5-9_en.pdf) from the Norwegian AIP:

[image]

The dotted lines from AND, SJA, FS and EVD to the IAFs are arrival routes containing arrival segments. These are the eqvivalent to feeder routes in TERPS, as they are defined equally.